# Is there a race condition in the linux ARM spinlock?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arm, spinlock

Here is the Linux implementation of a spinlock from [`arch/arm/include/asm/spinlock.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/include/asm/spinlock.h):

```
static inline void arch_spin_lock(arch_spinlock_t *lock)
{
    unsigned long tmp;
    u32 newval;
    arch_spinlock_t lockval;

    prefetchw(&lock->slock);
    __asm__ __volatile__(
"1: ldrex   %0, [%3]\n"
"   add %1, %0, %4\n"
"   strex   %2, %1, [%3]\n"
"   teq %2, #0\n"
"   bne 1b"
    : "=&r" (lockval), "=&r" (newval), "=&r" (tmp)
    : "r" (&lock->slock), "I" (1 << TICKET_SHIFT)
    : "cc");

    while (lockval.tickets.next != lockval.tickets.owner) {
        wfe();
        lockval.tickets.owner = READ_ONCE(lock->tickets.owner);
    }

    smp_mb();
}

...

static inline void arch_spin_unlock(arch_spinlock_t *lock)
{
    smp_mb();
    lock->tickets.owner++;
    dsb_sev();
}
```

My concern is that the following two lines in `arch_spin_lock`:

```
    while (lockval.tickets.next != lockval.tickets.owner) {
        wfe();
```

are not atomic. So what if `arch_spin_unlock` was called in between these two lines? This means in the function `arch_spin_lock` the `WFE` instruction would be run but the `SEV` has already been run and won't be run again. So at the very worst `arch_spin_lock` would wait forever, or until some unrelated event occurs.

Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding something? If it is a problem even only in theory, is there a way to avoid the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/20e260b6f4f717c100620122f626a2c06a4cfd72

Comment: The actual lock happened before these lines. And what you pointed out is the wait for unlock event. This is exactly what code expects (other task will call unlock). This is my understanding how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing this bit of WFE documentation:

> If the Event Register is set, WFE clears it and returns immediately.

In the "race" you describe `WFE` will get executed, but will return immediately, then `while` loop will exit.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the piece of information I was missing. Thanks!